# How to get the number of days one user has had consecutive days off work? [SQL]

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the number of days one worker has been off work consecutively.

These are the simple relevant values

```
## PersNr   |||     Date
  
----------
  

34030000301 |28.10.2019

34030000302 |15.07.2019

34030000302 |16.07.2019

34030000302 |17.07.2019

34030001087 |23.09.2019

34030002105 |30.09.2019    -single day

34030002105 |01.10.2019

34030002105 |02.10.2019

34030002105 |03.10.2019

34030002105 |04.10.2019

34030002105 |05.10.2019

34030002105 |06.10.2019

34030002105 |07.10.2019

34030002105 |08.10.2019

34030002105 |09.10.2019

34030002105 |10.10.2019

34030002105 |11.10.2019

34030002105 |12.10.2019

34030002105 |13.10.2019

34030002105 |14.10.2019

34030002105 |15.10.2019

34030002105 |16.10.2019

34030002105 |17.10.2019

34030002105 |18.10.2019

34030002105 |19.10.2019

34030002105 |20.10.2019
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------------

What I need is a table that combines all consecutive day one worker has been off work.

Like:

```
PersNR | StartDate | EndDate | Number_of_days_gone

34030000302 | 15.07.2019 | 17.07.2019 | 3

34030002105 | 30.09.2019 | 30.09.2019 | 1

34030002105 | 01.10.2019 | 20.10.2019 | 20

#---------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include your SQL code that shows your attempt at solving this.

Comment: I've been trying for some time now and so i managed to get myself into a state of "delete all- did not work" -> "start anew."

I did not manage to get any near a solution, for my sql skills a quite fresh.

"thanks for editing the post for more readability"

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem that you can solve with date arithmetic.  However, the date/time functions vary a lot among databases, so this gives an idea:

```
select persnr, min(date), max(date), count(*) as num_days
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by persnr order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by persnr, (date - seqnum * interval '1 day');
```

The idea is to subtract a sequence number from `date`.  Adjacent rows with incrementing values will have the same difference.  For instance:

```
2019-01-15      1   ==>   2019-01-14
2019-01-16      2   ==>   2019-01-14
2019-01-17      3   ==>   2019-01-14
2019-01-20      4   ==>   2019-01-16
```